# Possible to gain more control over merging in Github For Windows?

Tags: git, version-control, github-for-windows

I'm using git in the context of git-tfs. However, this doesn't matter as far as Github For Windows is concerned. The main pain point for me is that there are a few files that I must update and basically never check in. Right now my structure is a Work branch where I do my work in, and then the Master branch is exact same as TFS's source code. So of course, when I make changes, I need to merge from Work to Master.

Is it possible with Github For Windows to NOT merge over some files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but you could have a look at that :
http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html

You will just have problems if there is modifications on the files in your master branch...